# Send filtered associated records from controller to serializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-model-serializers

I am working on a Rails application using AMS. I have items and categories, with a one-to-many relationship. Items can be filtered in the controller. This works fine with the Items index action because I can just send a filtered array to the serializer:

**items_controller.rb**

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController

    def index
        items = Item.all
        if maxprice = params[:maxprice]
            items = items.where('price <= ?', (maxprice.to_i))
        end
        render json: items, each_serializer: ItemIndexSerializer, status: 200       
    end

end
```

The problem is with the Category show action, where I want to send back the associated items and still be able to filter them in the controller. I found a very dirty way to do this by sending the maxprice parameter to the serializer and filtering the items afterwards, something like

**categories_controller.rb**

```
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController

    def show
        category = Category.find(params[:id])   
        render json: category, serializer: CategoryShowSerializer, status: 200, maxprice: params[:maxprice] 
    end

end
```

**category_show_serializer.rb**

```
class CategoryShowSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer

    has_many :items, serializer: ItemIndexSerializer

    def items
        items = object.items
        if maxprice = @options[:maxprice]
            items = items.where('price <= ?', (maxprice.to_i))
        end
    end

end
```

However, this is possibly alright with such a simple scenario (which is not the case in my real app) but I'd like to be able to do the filtering in the Categories controller and send a category object with the filtered products array to the serializer. Any thoughts on how to do this?

*EDIT*

The temporary fix I am using for this is to define an `attr_accessor :filtered_items` on the Category model and then assigning the filtered items array to `category.filtered_items` in the controller. In this way, I can define items as `object.filtered_items` in the serializer.

This works but still feels somehow hacky (I don't think I should define a new attribute on the model to filter an association) and I'd rather get some feedback from the community instead of posting this solution as an accepted answer.

Comment: did you find a solution for this? I have the same problem to solve.

Comment: No, in the end I left the `attr_accessor` solution.

Comment: Thanks for responding, I also have not found a better solution yet. :(